# Windows Phone 8 not interfacing with Zune software

Tags: usb, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I just got a Lumia 521 with Windows Phone 8 and am trying to get the device to work with the Zune software on my PC.  I still have my Windows Phone 7 device, and the new one is not working the same way.  When I plug the WP7 device into the PC's USB port, it automatically fires up Zune and I can sync my podcasts and music etc to the device.  But when I plug the Lumia into the PC it doesn't fire up Zune, and if I start Zune manually, it doesn't interface with the phone at all.

Perhaps I am missing something and WP8 isn't supposed to use Zune to interface with the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I can now answer my own question.

The answer is: NO.

Disappointing, but apparently they decided against interfacing WP8 with Zune.  Which sucks because the Zune software is quite good.  Or, at least I like it.

Apparently there is an app you can install on the phone that enables syncing with your PC, but it only works for Windows 7 and 8.  Unfortunately, I'm still stuck on Vista.  Info about this app is here: [Windows Phone App for Desktop](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop?wa=wsignin1.0).

I got this information from [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpstart/can-you-still-sync-your-wp8-with-the-zune-software/ef515f65-b38d-4613-bedc-af4d5ef64b1b)